# Vb.net PRTSC (Screen capture) - Error

Tags: vb.net, screen, bmp, take

Hi again my question this time its related with this piece of code, im using the visual studio beta 2012, i cant seem to find the issue, if you guys could help me out ill appreciate it

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub fullScreen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fullScreen.Click
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{PRTSC}")
        Dim clip As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        If clip.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
            Dim screenCapture As Bitmap = CType(clip.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
            screenCapture.Save("C:\fullScreenCapture.bmp")
        End If
        Clipboard.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

Additional information: Error genérico en GDI+.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a screen shot more easily by using the following (send keys is always hit and miss in my experience)

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot() As Bitmap
    Dim scrn As Screen = Screen.FromControl(Me)
    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(scrn.Bounds.Width, scrn.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(scrn.Bounds.X, scrn.Bounds.Y), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)
    Return screenGrab
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to capture the screen? Why not use VS' classes to capture the screen?

[http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51761-creating-a-screen-shot-tool-vbnet](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51761-creating-a-screen-shot-tool-vbnet/)